# Call Specific Function From Behavior CakePHP 2.10.12 Not Working

Tags: cakephp, behavior, cakephp-2.x

Hay. Currently I'm creating a function in Behaviour in CakePHP 2.10.12 as shown below :

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeTime', 'Utility');
App::uses('CakeNumber', 'Utility');
class ConverterBehavior extends ModelBehavior {
    private $timezone;
    private $locale;
    private $currency;

    function hellow() {
        return "Hellow from behavior";
    }

    function initConverter($locale, $timezone, $currency) {
        $this->locale = $locale;
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
        $this->currency = $currency;
        setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
    }

    public function getCurrentLocale() {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    function convertCurrency($currencyAmount) {
        return CakeNumber::currency($currencyAmount, $this->currency);
    }

    function convertDate($date) {
        return CakeTime::i18nFormat($date, null, false, $this->timezone);
    }

}
?>
```

Then above behavior is used by my model as shown below :

```
<?php

class Test extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Converter');
}
```

And then I call the function that I created from behavior in my Controller as shown below :

```
public function converterModel() {
    $this->Test->initConverter('ja_JP', 'Asia/Tokyo', 'JPY');
    $temp = $this->Test->convertCurrency(23456789901.123456);
    debug($this->Test->hellow());
    // $this->set('jpDate', $this->Test->convertDate(new DateTime));
}
```

The problem is `initConverter` cannot be initialized. I check the variabel that are inputed from controller and all of those variabel are null (it's weird). But when I call the `hellow(`) (function in behavior), the result is displayed in my view. So is there something missing here ?
Thank you

Note :
This is the error message displayed in my view :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the warning/notice, you are receiving an object where you expect a string/number.

The first argument of an externally invoked behavior method will always be the instance of the model that the behavior is attached to, ie your method signatures should be like:

```
function initConverter(Model $model, $locale, $timezone, $currency)

function convertCurrency(Model $model, $currencyAmount)

// etc...
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Behaviors > Creating Behaviors](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#creating-behaviors)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Behaviors > Creating behavior methods](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#creating-behavior-methods)**